# how to set Connection Timeout with jndi?

Tags: java, sql, jndi, connection-pooling

i have this code:

```
Object objc = null;

if (jdbcFactory == null) {
  try {
    InitialContext c = new InitialContext();
    this.jdbcFactory = (DataSource) c.lookup(this.jndiName);

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

  }
}
// jdbcFactory initiated.
try {
  objc = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();  
} catch (Exception e) {

}
return objc;
}
```

how can i set connection timeout ? (without using context.xml )

Comment: without using context.xml means you want to reset from code itself?

Comment: yes i want to set connection timeout from code

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are casting the `this.jdbcFactory` to the `javax.sql.DataSource`; according to the code this interface extends `javax.sql.CommonDataSource` which defines the following method `javax.sql.CommonDataSource#setLoginTimeout`

This method documentation states that it:

```
 * <p>Sets the maximum time in seconds that this data source will wait
 * while attempting to connect to a database.  A value of zero
 * specifies that the timeout is the default system timeout
 * if there is one; otherwise, it specifies that there is no timeout.
 * When a <code>DataSource</code> object is created, the login timeout is
 * initially zero.
```